# Is "I could tell you write" correct

Tags: grammar

Is there supposed to be a comma after could to indicate a pause. I am a bit confused.

Comment: What are you trying to say?  The sentence is valid and reasonably idiomatic if you mean that you sensed that the individual you are talking to is a writer.

Comment: @HotLicks yes, that's what I meant. Thank you.

Comment: Note that "I could tell, you write" (with the comma) would be apt to be interpreted as a crude way of saying "I'll tell you stuff and you write it down."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“I could tell you write” is fine.

Try substituting perceive, or observe, for tell. Also insert *that* after tell. “You write” is used as a description of a habitual activity—the person who writes is an author, not just someone temporarily jotting something down.

So, it means “I was able to perceive that you are a writer,” (or at least someone who tries to be a writer).

Comment: Okay, that's what I meant. Thanks.